# Watson Conversation API Unity SDK widget vs HTTP call

Tags: unity-game-engine, sdk, watson, watson-conversation

I'm experiencing inconsistent message responses with the conversation api using the unity SDK widget vs a standard HTTP call.

When testing my conversation bot within the Watson console's simulator or using Postman & hitting the message POST endpoint: `/v1/workspaces/{workspace_id}/message` I receive the desired response which hits my `Anything_else` "catch all" node with the appropriate output.text message.

When using the Watson Unity SDK to interact with my bot, specifically:

> m_Conversation.Message(OnMessage, m_WorkspaceID, messageRequest)

Where I've tried to mimic my exact Postman HTTP body in that messageRequest

I never get to my `Anything_else` node or get the desired output.text. Instead Watson assigns it to the highest matching intent I see when passing up `alternate_intents: true` (which is a very low % match)

Any tips or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the Version of the conversation service in the Unity SDK. In the Conversation DataModel file, replace

```
public const string VERSION = "2016-09-20";
```

with

```
public const string VERSION = "2017-05-26";
```

In the upcoming 1.0 major release of the Watson Unity SDK the user will define the `VERSION` instead of having the version hard coded.

Comment: Worked like a champ! Appreciate the quick response.